# Should I use Mockito doAnswer for testing a delete method in Java?

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mockito, junit5

I want to write a Unit Test for testing `productRepository.delete` method:

```
public void delete(UUID uuid) {
        final Product product = productRepository.findByUuid(uuid)
                        .orElseThrow(() -> new EntityNotFoundException(PRODUCT));
        productRepository.delete(product);
}
```

However, I have really no idea on what is the proper approach for testing this method. Some approaches use `verify`, but I think it is not good idea as it just check if the `productRepository`'s  delete method is called or not. Instead of this, I am thinking something e.g. `doAnswer(AdditionalAnswers.returnsFirstArg()).when(productRepository).delete(any());`, but not sure if this is the most proper way for testing `productRepository.delete`. So, how can I test it properly?

Comment: You can pass an argument to the `verify` method to make sure that the right key is passed to `productRepository.delete`.

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem Do you mean using ArgumentCaptor? Any example pls?

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem Any reply pls?

Answer (score 1):

You can test two things:

1. Verify that delete() is called with the right argument and
2. that the EntityNotFoundException is thrown for a non existant UUID

Best way to do this is by mocking the productRepository delete() method as you
mention and by throwing the expected exception on a call to
productRepository.findByUuid(uuid) `when(productRepositoryMock.findByUuid(uuid)).thenThrow(new EntityNotFoundException(PRODUCT)));`

The [Mockito documentation](https://javadoc.io/doc/org.mockito/mockito-core/latest/org/mockito/Mockito.html#3) makes a bit clearer:

> For information solely on custom argument matchers check out javadoc for ArgumentMatcher class (for non-trivial method arguments used in stubbing or verification).

> Be reasonable with using complicated argument matching. The natural matching style using equals() with occasional anyX() matchers tend to give clean & simple tests. Sometimes it's just better to refactor the code to allow equals() matching or even implement equals() method to help out with testing.

Comment: Thanks amigo, but I already check exception. The problem is checking `productRepository.delete(product)`. Should I use verify to test that part? Or should I use `ArgumentCaptor` , etc. Any example code pls?

Comment: Verify is fine if you only want to be shure that the right argument is passed to delete method. ArgumentCaptor is IMHO appropirate if you need the argument to control further behavior of your test (e.g. evaluating return values, e.t.c).

Comment: But as far as I see, the general idea is `ArgumentCaptor` is not needed when the tested method returns value (entity). So, I just use `ArgumentCaptor` when I cannot reach the returned value, etc. Is that better?